# Play Framework's Json.fromJson returns Scala object in Java project

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I have a project that builds HTTP requests using Play's Json.fromJson method, but it returns an object containing Scala lists, which then causes an Exception when I try to parse it.

Running:

```
final Result result = controller.emailFilterSave(Helpers.fakeRequest().bodyJson(Json.toJson(request)).build());

        // test response
        final Map<String, Object> response = Json.fromJson(Json.parse(Helpers.contentAsString(result)),
                Map.class);

        assertEquals(HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, result.status());
        assertEquals("email", response.get("field"));
        assertEquals("Email address is not valid", ((List<String>)response.get("errors")).get(0));
```

Causes an exception:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to java.util.List`

How can I make it so that the json is parsed using Java classes?

Potentially relevant imports in the above class are:

```
import io.ebean.Ebean;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

import play.libs.Json;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.Result;
```

My build.sbt is:

```
name := """accepter"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
                    

scalaVersion := "2.12.12"

retrieveManaged := true

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaWs,
  filters,
  evolutions,
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.200",
  "org.mariadb.jdbc" % "mariadb-java-client" % "2.7.3",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-sns" % "1.11.1034",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.8.8",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-guice" % "2.8.8",
  "com.github.dwickern" %% "swagger-play2.8" % "3.1.0",
  "io.swagger" % "swagger-core" % "1.6.2",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-modules-java8" % "2.11.4"
)

EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile)
EclipseKeys.projectFlavor := EclipseProjectFlavor.Java 
EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.ValueSet(EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedClasses, EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedResources)

Test / javaOptions += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf"
```

plugins.sbt

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.1")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.2")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.2")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.10")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.2")
addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.5.1")

// Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for public fields
// and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. Remove this
// plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per project
// basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.2.2")


addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.4")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "6.0.0")
```

Comment: What are your `import`s? Especially the one for `Json`

Comment: @GaëlJ I've added potentially relevant imports to the original post

Comment: Casting is a bad bad idea. Check the types and work with it.

Comment: Imports looks good, dependencies are smelly as you are depending on Scala version of play libraries but I'm not familiar with doing Java stuff with SBT..

Comment: You can try using Scala's implicit converters (import scala.collection.JavaConverters), but It's not a good practice, are you sure about `response` object type? It's an object of type Map[String, Any], and play does not serializer/deserialize objects of type Any (Object type in Java) by default! and also, Map.class desn't seem right since Map is not a class, try passing Map<String, Object>.class as fromJson second parameter.

Comment: Its probably not the right way, bit following on from @cchantep's comment, I tried casting it direct to a `scala.collection.immutable.List` object, and it actually worked - so that will do for now, thanks